# Getting Data from Multiple Excel Files

Tags: c#, excel

How do I grab data from multiple excel files in a folder and export to a new file using C#?

[Data that needs to be exported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNssw.png)

I need those values of Atten1, Idrive1,Idrive2, and Gates1 each on their own worksheet with the Temps all on one file. Please help.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sc8O.png)

The output should look like this.

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: Use a library that can read excel files.

Comment: Please note, stackoverflow is a knowledge base of programming questions and answers. Its not a free development website. At the moment you don't really have a programming problem, however you can make your question better! Take a look at [ask]

Comment: Step 1) Pick an Excel library you want use to read/write the Excel Files. There are many to chose from. Some are free... others not so free. If you have MS Office on your machine interop is an option. I suggest you take a look at EPPlus. Pick you your own poison for the first step, then which ever one you pick should dictate “how” to do the rest.